# Adding dynamically a style to an object (ComboBox)

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm building an app for generating some HTML template.
I'm currently creating the frontend.

I figured out how to create a style for a combobox, but I'm searching how to apply it.

Here's the style `ComboBoxLS` :

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxLS" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,5,3"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Here's my actual condition :

```
if (index == 0)
                {
                    MainGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(237, 237, 237));
                    OKbut.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(234, 209, 28));

                    Logo.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(237, 237, 237));
                    // this does not work
                }
```

How can I apply it in C# on my combobox named `Logo` ? I saw I could do `Logo.Style = something` but I don't undertand how to use it or even it is the right method.

Answer (score 0):

To apply a style, which is in the `<Window.Resources>` portion of the Xaml file, use this in your code behind file:

```
Logo.Style = (Style) this.FindResource("ComboBoxLS");
```